# Is this soldering iron and power supply combo grounded and if so, how?

Tags: safety, grounding, tools

I'm interested in [a TS100 soldering iron](https://www.ebay.com/itm/65W-TS100-TS-BC2-Mini-Portable-Programmable-Electric-Soldering-Iron-Digital-LCD/232958881883) as a decent starter iron and a light one that doesn't take up too much space. It doesn't come with a power supply though, presumably to keep it flexible as it can take 12-24V input (max 65W usage). So I found [this 24V power supply](https://www.ebay.com/itm/ABI-24V-3A-AC-Adapter-Power-Supply-Driver-for-24V-LED-Strip-Light-/361306136292) to go with it.

Here's the iron:
[image: TS100 soldering iron]

Here's the power supply purchased separately:
[image: 24V AC/DC adapter]

My question is whether this device is grounded and if so how, or if not, is it safe to use or does it risk shorting out into the user? I would think it is not grounded since most AC/DC adapter barrel connector power supplies I find are only 2-prong (is it necessarily only 2-prong). In that case, I'd hope the device is insulated - how would one check that?

The closest thing I could find to a spec sheet for this iron is here: https://imgmgr.banggood.com/images/upload/2015/11/TS100/TS100%20Soldering%20Iron%20Instruction%20Manual.pdf It mentions a ground screw and connecting a ground wire to that. Does that imply that for safe use of the device, I'd need to - in addition to the power supply - have a ground wire clipped under that screw and connected on the other end to a reliable ground like copper plumbing pipes?

Comment: I recommend that you add some photos into your question so it's clear what you're asking without following links all of which will die soon (auction site ads) and render your question useless for future readers. You'll also attract more / better answers.

Comment: @Transistor good point, sorry about that. Posted a couple pics

Comment: see that screw between the display and the cable connector? .... that is the grounding screw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use any regular ac/dc brick, it is not grounded.
You should not use the iron when it is not grounded.

Why you must ground it?
When you use a "floating" ac/dc brick, there will be charge or coupled AC current (typically half mains voltage) on the DC side of the transformer. Although small, it still has the capability of sparking any other circuitry to death. Just like ESD.

Even if a AC/DC brick has a three prong plug, this does not guarantee grounded DC side.

Explicitly ground the iron or DC side of the power supply yourself.

*Many other soldering stations have a large mains transformer instead of a [SMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply), this significantly reduces the leakage current to almost zero. You could use these when they are not grounded.*

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info about those ac/dc bricks. With that said, I guess it's part of this iron being small and portable that it inevitably needs its own ground.